# Not able to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response provided by Spring Boot Application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

Please read the question. I tried all answers on Stack Overflow.

**Error:**

```
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must 
not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The 
credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by 
the withCredentials attribute.
```

**Front End Running on Port 4200 in Angular:**

```
let headers = new Headers({
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers ,withCredentials:true});

//body contains username and password.
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/login',{body}, options).
subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)    
});
```

**Back End Running on Port 8080 using Spring Boot:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200",allowCredentials="true")
@RestController
public class SecurityApplication {
...  //Rest Api's
}
//Security Config
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        cors().and().httpBasic().and().formLogin()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/", "/home", "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

I am hitting */login* api which is provided by Spring Security.

I referred https://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-cors-integration-using-crossorigin-annotation-xml-filter-example and according to it **origins = "http://localhost:4200"** should set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**  in response header to value provided to it,but Still I am getting wildcard '*' as a response.

I tried corsFilters but didn't worked. I have CORS extension enabled in Chrome browser.I want to know why it is not setting **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to value which I provided and how to resolve it.

Comment: Do you have any `CorsConfigurationSource` exposed?

Comment: Yeah I tried that by referring this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html) but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is not to set Cross Origin. Instead, in your angular application, create a proxy file, proxy.conf.json and when starting up your angular, use

```
ng serve --proxy-conf proxy.conf.json
```

The contents of your proxy.conf.json will then be:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080/api",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": "true",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        } 
    }
}
```

and then finally in your application.properties in spring boot application you can set:

```
server.context-path=/api
```

All your requests to api will hit your spring boot app via the api context path, and there won't be a cross origin error.

Your call on angular will be:

```
this.http.post('/api/login',{body}, options).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)    
});
```

Comment: I am not sure but, wont that violet any Security Policy?Will I be able to Setup it in Actual production Environment with this way?

Comment: You can read more here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md